# Null pointer exception on broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-widget, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use a broadcast receiver to change the text on a texview of a homescreen widget on the press of a button. However im getting a nullpointer exception on my widget with the code i currently have and logcat appears to be useless on a widget with the debug disconnecting after about 4 - 5 seconds. ANy help help is very much appreciated :)

Broadcast Reciver:

```
package kevin.erica.box;



public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Random rgenerator = new Random();
private Random rgenerator2 = new Random();
private String [] myString1;
private String myStringRandom = myString1[rgenerator.nextInt(myString1.length)];

public static final String TEST_INTENT= "MyTestIntent";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());

  Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
  RemoteViews rViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
            rViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget1label, "someupdateddata");
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, rViews);


}
```

My widget activity:

```
package kevin.erica.box;




public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {




private Random rgenerator = new Random();
private Random rgenerator2 = new Random();
private String[] myString1;






  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
      Resources res = context.getResources();
        myString1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);


    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    Log.i("ExampleWidget",  "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));
    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
      // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
      Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(TestReceiver.TEST_INTENT);
        intent.setClassName(TestReceiver.class.getPackage().getName(), TestReceiver.class.getName());
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
      // to the button
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagewidgeterica, pendingIntent);
      // To update a label
      views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget1label , myString1[rgenerator.nextInt(myString1.length)]);
      // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
      // widget
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


     }

}


         }
```

Comment: Fixed it, just put                                             Resources res = context.getResources();
     myString1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); In the onrecieve bit